# How Can I keep a object forever?

Tags: c++, serialization

I have a class, which is very similiar with a database.

It read a lot of file, and record the data. waiting to be used to search.

For Example:

```
std::vector<std::string> files = {"a", "b", ....}; // not real code, just to show, there is a lot of files
Class BigBuddy {
 private:
  BigBuddy() { read();}
 public:
  static BigBuddy& Inst() {static BigBuddy b; return b;}
  void read() {
     for (const auto & file : files) {
       // read the file, and save data into unordered_map
     }
  }
  // this class is created once in constructor
  // then it only can be used to find/search
  std::string get(int i) const { return data.at(i); }
  std::unordered_map<int, std::string> data;
};
```

This is a `singleton` class, becuase it may be used in several place in my project.

for user, it may be:

```
int main() {
  BigBuddy& b = BigBuddy::Inst();
  b.get(3);
}
```

the problem is:

I may run this project many times a day,  the `BigBuddy` will be created for each time, which cost long time. (create `BigBuddy` is slow, because the heavy `read` function)

For Example, `BigBuddy` cost `5`s to read, i run this project `100` times a day. the project running cost `10`s. the total running time is `(10 + 5) * 100`, but i think i can decrese to `10*100+5`. Because the BigBuddy class's data changed every friday.

So, my question is: Is there any method can make the `BigBuddy` class stay in memory, only update in friday?

ps. I have tried `boost.serialization`, but i perfer not to use it, because link external library `boost` is not good for my project, and, the serialization gives me a lot of error, because the real `BigBuddy` in my project has many complex class inside.

Comment: You could store it in an in-memory cache running on the same server as the project, but it will still require you to serialize the class in order to store it.

Comment: There seem to be only 2 options here: keep a program (service) running that does provide access to the data and update/restart it on fridays or find a more efficient way of accessing the data. (After the process is done, there's no way to regain access to the memory.) If you're really close to a db, an embedded db such as sqlite may provide an efficient way of doing so.

Comment: It depends somewhat on the architecture of your system: whether you are on Windows or another OS; whether BigBuddy is only needed on one machine, or accessible via other users over the network. One solution for a Windows PC is to create an out-of-process COM server (possibly as a service) that keeps BigBuddy in memory and provides an interface to it. Not a simple task though.

Comment: @fabian the reason i dont use db is that i need this fast enough, so i designed this kind of this struct, but the load do bothers me.

Comment: @DS_London I am using linux Centos, I think linux may have the same api function, but i dont find any simple tutorial

Comment: "Databases are slow" is a long debunked myth. Always go for simplicity and maintainability first hand, and only if performance isn't "Good Enough" (which alarmingly often *is* good enough) and you have specific requirements about performance, you measure, profile and benchmark to find the top-two bottlenecks and fix those two. If it turns out to be database-related, then it's often more likely because of using it in a bad way.

Comment: @nick The "bad thing" about reading files is that you're reading a lot of data from the hd. Depending on the requirements you may get away with reading only parts of the data by creating indices, or something similar which an embedded db could help with. There's not enough info to determine, if this could work for you though...

Comment: @fabian touches on an important point: does every user of BigBuddy need all the data, or just part of it. BigBuddy is already a database, so you don’t want to reinvent the wheel. There might also be scope to load the data asynchronously while your code is doing something else. Also, if you are running the project 100 times/day, why not just have it sit in ‘wait’ mode between runs?

Comment: On win32 you could use a *Named Shared Memory*, the first instance of your program creates (and updates) the mapped object, the others just access it.  No need of serialization, but you'll have to implement the proper synchronization mechanisms.

Comment: There's no keyword `Class` in C++.

Comment: Does the code have to be cross-platform, or does it just have to work on Linux?

Comment: @LHLaurini just linux

Answer (score 0):

> So, my question is: Is there any method can make the BigBuddy class stay in memory, only update in friday?

Yes: Instead of running the program multiple times, keep the program running constantly. That way to object will remain in memory.

If the premise of stopping and re-running the program is necessary, then: No, there is no way to keep the object in memory in standard C++.

You could of course split the program into two programs. One program that runs constantly and keeps the object in memory, and another program that is run on request.

A program that runs constantly and keeps objects in memory is called "in-memory database". There are existing projects that implement such database, so you don't need to bother building it from the ground up. Since your data is an unordered map, a key-value database would be appropriate.

---

> This is a singleton class, becuase it may be used in several place in my project.

That's not a good reason to use a singleton class.

Comment: "If the premise of stopping and re-running the program is necessary, then: No, there is no way to keep the object in memory." This is not true. One can create named shared memory in POSIX (with `shm_open`) and in Windows with [CreateFileMapping or OpenFileMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory).

Comment: @LHLaurini I've amended the answer. Note that one cannot store a non-trivial object such as `std::unordered_map` in shared memory.

Comment: I think you can, as long as you use a custom allocator that only uses shared memory.

Comment: @LHLaurini I'm not sure that would work. There's no guarantee that the shared memory would be mapped to the same address in each process.

Comment: You're right. The program can ask for a specific address, but there's still no guarantee that the system will honor it (at least Linux may not).

Answer (score 0):

You can use named shared memory, which will survive until a reboot. However, the standard containers won't work with shared memory, unless you implement a custom allocator and can guarantee a fixed memory location, which is difficult to do.

The best choice is to either write new containers yourself, or use a library. Fortunately, I found [a library on GitHub](https://github.com/mikewei/shm_container) that provides such containers (shame it seems kinda abandoned).

```
#include "shmc/shm_hash_map.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Tweak these values to your needs
#define SHM_KEY "0x123456"
#define SHM_MAX_KEYS 100  // max number of keys
#define SHM_NODE_SIZE 100 // size of each node used to store values
#define SHM_NUM_NODES 100 // total number of nodes for values storage

class BigBuddy {
private:
  BigBuddy() { read(); }

public:
  static BigBuddy &Inst() {
    static BigBuddy b;
    return b;
  }
  void read() {
    if (!data.InitForRead(SHM_KEY)) {
      if (!data.InitForWrite(SHM_KEY, SHM_MAX_KEYS, SHM_NODE_SIZE,
                             SHM_NUM_NODES)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to initialized shm");
      }

      std::cout << "Reading data from disk\n";

      // put some dummy data in the map
      data.Insert(-50, "negative fifty");
      data.Insert(5, "five");
      data.Insert(123, "one hundred and twenty-three");
      data.Insert(999, "nine hundred and ninety-nine");

    } else {
      std::cout << "Read data from memory\n";
    }
  }
  // this class is created once in constructor
  // then it only can be used to find/search
  std::string get(int i) const {
    std::string r;
    if (!data.Find(i, &r)) {
      throw std::out_of_range(std::to_string(i));
    }
    return r;
  }
  shmc::ShmHashMap<int> data;
};

int main() {
  std::cout << BigBuddy::Inst().get(-50) << "\n";
  std::cout << BigBuddy::Inst().get(5) << "\n";
  std::cout << BigBuddy::Inst().get(123) << "\n";
  std::cout << BigBuddy::Inst().get(999) << "\n";
}
```

First run:

```
Reading data from disk
negative fifty
five
one hundred and twenty-three
nine hundred and ninety-nine
```

Second run:

```
Read data from memory
negative fifty
five
one hundred and twenty-three
nine hundred and ninety-nine
```

It uses `shmget` by default (which is why the key is hexadecimal), but you can also use normal POSIX shared memory too.